# How to block specific e-mail address using an online form

Tags: php, forms, email

I am new here, especially with PHP. I have a online Contact Us form.
Within the FormValidate.php file I have this string of code and I need to add or modify a string of code to BLOCK (error will show saying "invalid e-mail address") certain e-mail addresses ending in .de and .it

Here below is the string of code that I have. I believe it needs to be implemented.

```
private function validEmail($value) {
        $exp = '/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i';
        if (!preg_match($exp, $value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use regex to validate email addresses. PHP has special modules for it. It sounds like you need something like this:

```
private function validEmail($value) {
    if (!$value || !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return false; 
    if (preg_match('#@example\.org$#uiD', $value) === 1) return false;
    if (preg_match('#@example\.net$#uiD', $value) === 1) return false;
    return true;
}
```

It returns `false` for invalid email addresses, or for 2 blacklisted domains (regexpatterns), and true for any other valid email addr.

Comment: Amazing! Exactly how I wanted to be. Thanks!!!